# Finding the count of repetitions of words (Clips)

Tags: clips

I have a task, write a program to count the number of repetitions of a word in the list.

I just started learning the clips so I do not know many things.

I wrote the code, but unfortunately it does not work, what could be the error?

```
(clear) 
(deftemplate list_1
    (slot numeral)
)
(deftemplate list_2
    (slot numeral)
)
(deftemplate list_3
    (slot numeral)
)
(deffacts start 
    (list_1 (numeral zero))
    (list_1 (numeral one)) 
    (list_1 (numeral two))  
    (list_2 (numeral zero))
    (list_2 (numeral two))
    (list_2 (numeral three)) 
    (list_3 (numeral zero)) 
    (list_3 (numeral one))
    (list_3 (numeral three))     
)
(defglobal 
    ?*countword* = 0 
)
(defrule inputword 
    (initial-fact)
    => 
    (printout t crlf “Enter a word to search for: “) 
    (bind ?i (read))
    (assert (wordforsearch ?i))
)
(defrule searchword 
    (wordforsearch ?i)  
    (list_1 (numeral ?i))
    (list_2 (numeral ?i))
    (list_3 (numeral ?i))
    => 
    (bind ?*countword* (+ ?*countword* 1))
) 
(defrule outputword 
    (wordforsearch ?i)
    => 
    (printout t "Number of repetitions for a word: " ?i " = " ?*countword* crlf) 
    (reset)     
    (halt)
)   
(run)
```

I really hope the same way that you explain in detail what the error is and maybe tell me another version of the implementation of the code.

P. S. I implemented another version of the program - the search for the number of repetitions of words in the sentence. This code also does not work.

```
(clear) 
(defglobal 
    ?*countword* = 0 
)
(defrule inputword
    (initial-fact)
    => 
    (printout t crlf “Enter a sentence: “) 
    (bind ?s (read))    
)
(defrule inputword 
    (?s)
    => 
    (printout t crlf “Enter a word to search for: “) 
    (bind ?i (read))
    (assert (wordforsearch ?i))
)
(defrule searchword 
    (wordforsearch ?i)
    (?s ?i) 
    => 
    (bind ?*countword* (+ ?*countword* 1))
) 
(defrule outputword 
    (wordforsearch ?i)
    => 
    (printout t "Number of repetitions for a word: " ?i " = " ?*countword* crlf) 
    (reset)     
    (halt)
)   
(run)
```

I really hope for your help in understanding the clips.

P. P. S. Sorry for my english

Comment: It is not necessary to add the initial-fact to a rule with no other conditions; it is added automatically in versions of CLIPS prior to version 6.3. The initial-fact functionality was deprecated in the 6.3 release; it is still asserted by a reset, but rules without conditions no longer rely on it. In the 6.4 release, the initial-fact is no longer asserted, so rules that explicitly match this fact will no longer be activated.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer here this option. This has many shortcomings, but as an example this will suitable.

```
(defglobal 
    ?*i* = 0    
    ?*count* = 0
    ?*string* = (create$)
    ?*wordsearch* = ""
    ?*wordsearch1* = (create$)
)

(defrule Searching
    ?fact <- (searching)
    =>
    (retract ?fact)
    (bind ?*i* (+ ?*i* 1))
    (if (<= ?*i* (length ?*string*))
        then
            (if (eq ?*wordsearch1* (subseq$ ?*string* ?*i* ?*i*))
                then 
                    (bind ?*count* (+ ?*count* 1))
                    (assert (searching))
                else 
                    (assert (searching))
            )
        else    
            (printout t "Word " ?*wordsearch* " repeats " ?*count* " times" crlf)
    )
)

(defrule Start
    =>
    (printout t crlf "Enter the string: ")
    (bind ?*string* (create$ (explode$ (lowcase (readline)))))
    (printout t crlf "Enter a word to search for: ")
    (bind ?*wordsearch* (lowcase (readline)))
    (bind ?*wordsearch1* (create$ (explode$ ?*wordsearch*)))        
    (assert (searching))
)
```